# Custom log level in dropwizard 0.8.1 and redirect to another file

Tags: logging, jersey, slf4j, logback, dropwizard

I am using dropwizard 0.8.1 and I want to log with a custom(other than ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE) level and all the logs should be directed to a different file.People have suggested to use Markers, but I am not able to find a proper example/illustration (yml config).Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom appender (see FileAppenderFactory as example) and log whatever you want to your file. Its important that your implemenation extends AbstractAppenderFactory!

Then you have to create a file named
META-INF/services/io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory in your
resources directory which contains the fully qualified name of your
concrete implementation.

Or if you like it simple, then use [AsynchronousFileChannel](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-7%20).